# Azure Sql Serverless Vs Basic Tier

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure

Does anyone have experience of moving a database from an Azure SQL Basic, or Standard tier, to Serverless?

I'm currently investigating whether to do this for our development, UAT and staging databases, to hopefully save a bit of money. They're currently averaging between £5-£40/month each.

The workload for them seems ideal for serverless, a few hours use, then nothing for days / weeks at a time, but despite staring at lots of Microsoft's docs about DTU vs VCore pricing, I wouldn't say I feel entirely confident that the billing would actually be reduced if we did switch over.

Would switching to Serverless, at as similar a performance level as possible definitely reduce the bills? Has anyone got any real world experience of this working out?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a technical question about database administration but a question about cost of various licensing alternatives. You should ask your vendor.

Comment: I don't imagine we'll get anywhere discussing this here, but cloud db configuration isn't really just a licensing issue is it? The ever evolving options are so complex (as are the docs), that real world experience of them is incredibly valuable when making decisions that could well end up costing you a lot of money.

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly the benefit the programming manager of one of the companies I work with highlighted, he told me "with serverless we can test with the same performance level of the production database, but paying less. We will pay only for the specific period of times when we test".

Azure SQL Serverless application scenarios:

Examples:

- New apps when compute sizing requirements are unknown.
- Development/test workloads
- Line-of-business applications
- Content management systems, e-commerce and more.

Typical serverless usage patters are:

- Intermittent, unpredictable usage and lower average compute utilization over time.
- Frequently rescaled databases.
- New databases without usage history.

Usage patterns when serveless is not recommended:

- More regular, predictable usage and higher average compute utilization over time.
- Databases sensitive to performance trade-offs from scaling.
- Multiple databases that can be consolidated into elastic pools.

Price-performance shape (serverless).

- In terms of auto-scaling, min and max vcore range available to database.  Memory and IO limits proportional to vCore range selected.
- Database is auto-paused if inactive for long enough. Database is autoresumed when login is received.
- In terms of billing, compute billing is per second based on vcores and memory used. Minimum compute billed based on min vcores and min memory configured. Only the storage is billed when the database is paused.

The following image compares provisioned compute vs serverless compute.

[image]